# RedHat - yum install completion

Tags: redhat

I had been using Ubuntu and recently migrated to RedHat.
The `apt-get install` auto completion is very handy, so I supposed `yum install` should have this function as well, but seemed it doesn't.
Is there package name tab completion of `yum install` ?

Answer (score 4):

first check that you have the bash_completion package installed;

```
$ rpm -qa | grep compl
bash-completion-2.1-2.fc18.noarch
```

If you are on rhel/centos, check that it being sourced in your `.bashrc` file, like so;

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc | grep -A3 '\[ -f /etc/bash_completion \]'
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
   . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

otherwise bash_completions are loaded from `/etc/profile.d` on fedora;

```
$ ls -1 /etc/profile.d/ | grep compl
bash_completion.sh
udisks-bash-completion.sh
```

to test it, you can manually source the file, and see if it working as you want; (centos/rhel)

```
$ source /etc/bash_completion
```

if you are using fedora, you will need this instead;

```
$ source /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
```

**note:**

whether this is the best way to search for installable packages is debatable, but I actually didn't realise you could do this until I just tried....

```
$ yum install 
Display all 40991 possibilities? (y or n)

0ad-data.noarch
0ad-debuginfo.x86_64
0xFFFF-debuginfo.x86_64
0xFFFF.x86_64
389-admin-console-doc.noarch
389-admin-console.noarch
389-admin-debuginfo.x86_64
389-admin.i686
389-adminutil-debuginfo.x86_64
389-adminutil-devel.i686
389-adminutil-devel.x86_64
389-ds-base-libs.x86_64
389-ds-base.x86_64
389-ds-console-doc.noarch
```

...
...

etc etc

Comment: `bash-completion` rocks my world. It puts tab completion in all sorts of places, not just here.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following:

```
yum install bash-completion

source /etc/bash_completion
```